# How do I merge multiple table with condition

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 3 table Table A, B, C

table A data is

```
ID  C_Name  Status
4   ABC     Confirm
5   Xyz     Confirm
6   CDE     Pendinng
7   EFG     N/A
8   BBB     Confirm
9   CCC     Pending
10  ASE     Confirm
```

table B data is

```
ID  Name    Date    Amount
4   A    2014-11-01  2000
4   B    2014-11-02  3000
4   C    2014-11-20  1000
5   A    2014-10-01  2000
5   X    2014-10-10  1000
6   B    2014-03-30  3000
6   X    2014-04-01  1000
6   Z    2014-04-02  500
7   X    2014-12-01  1000
7   Y    2014-12-02  800
8   B    2014-11-15  3000
8   C    2014-11-15  1000
```

table C is

```
Name    dayOfPay    Pay     remark
B       2014-12-17  4000    Cash
C       2014-12-14  1000    Check
X       2014-12-01  2000    Online
```

This is my Table and data how i can show all data. if i select Name 'B' in table B where status = Confirm in table A. 
my query is

```
select a.C_Name, b.Name,b.Amount,b.Date, c.dayOfPay,c.Pay,c.remark
 from A a join B b on a.ID = b.ID join c c on b.Name = c.Name where b.Name = 'b' and a.Status = 'confirm'

C_Name  Name    Amount  Date        dayOfPay    Pay     remark
ABC     B       3000    2014-11-02  2014-12-17  4000    Cash
BBB     B       3000    2014-11-15  2014-12-17  4000    Cash
```

How i can show below Records

```
C_Name  Name    Amount  Date        dayOfPay    Pay remark
ABC     B        3000   2014-11-02      -        -    -
BBB     B        3000   2014-11-15      -        -    -
-       B        -      -          2014-12-17   4000    Cash
```

I need this show result this type.

Comment: You're going to need a Left Join. A Join is classed as an Inner Join and will only retrieve matching records.

Answer (score 0):

Use outer join ( left join ) , instead of inner ( join ).

```
    select a.C_Name, b.Name,b.Amount,b.Date, c.dayOfPay,c.Pay,c.remark
     from A a 
left join B b on a.ID = b.ID 
left join c c on b.Name = c.Name where b.Name = 'b' and a.Status = 'confirm'
```

Comment: So try full join instead of left join.. im really not sure what you need. And btw the result cant be the same when you use join or left join when i look at your tables, so maybe you are doing something wrong :)